# NSOpenPanel crash in sandbox inherited process

Tags: cocoa, appstore-sandbox, nsopenpanel

I have an application running in the sandbox which launches a helper application bundle using NSTask (the helper is contained within the bundle of the app).

Using the correct entitlements the main app is able to launch the helper using NSTask and the sandbox is inherited with no crashing. The only problem seems to be when I open an NSOpenPanel I get the crash below. Please note that the caller app does not crash when using NSOpenPanel, just the helper.

This looks like a bug in the system so maybe if someone has encountered this before there is a workaround for it.

Here are the entitlements for the main app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.usb</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.serial</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The entitlements for the helper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The crash when NSOpenPanel is opened:

```
2015-12-09 10:35:56.879 Desktops[29807:22090051] -[NSVBSavePanel init] caught non-fatal NSObjectNotAvailableException 'service com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService failed to init an instance of NSOpenPanelService on behalf of <NSLayerCentricRemoteView: 0x1077fd0> due to {
    callStackSymbols = (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f375e32 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff855084fa objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f3dc65d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService 0x000000010879493a com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService + 6458
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff87e4a662 -[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff87e4a5cd -[NSViewController view] + 30
    6   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff9180dbab -[NSViewServiceMarshal _bootstrap:replyData:] + 11432
    7   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff9180efb5 -[NSViewServiceMarshal bootstrap:withReply:] + 124
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e7b5c __invoking___ + 140
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e79ee -[NSInvocation invoke] + 286
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f302e36 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
    11  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff91847f01 -[NSVB_ViewServiceImplicitAnimationDecodingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 264
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e6472 ___forwarding___ + 514
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e61e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e7b5c __invoking___ + 140
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e79ee -[NSInvocation invoke] + 286
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f302e36 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
    17  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff918189fa -[NSVB_QueueingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 323
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e6472 ___forwarding___ + 514
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e61e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e7b5c __invoking___ + 140
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e79ee -[NSInvocation invoke] + 286
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f302e36 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e6472 ___forwarding___ + 514
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e61e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e7b5c __invoking___ + 140
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e79ee -[NSInvocation invoke] + 286
    27  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff918573db withHintInProgress + 501
    28  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff91857161 __deferNSXPCInvocationOntoMainThread_block_invoke_2 + 220
    29  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff917f5c3f +[NSViewServiceApplication withHostPID:invoke:] + 46
    30  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff9185702f __deferNSXPCInvocationOntoMainThread_block_invoke + 129
    31  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff91856c3a __deferBlockOntoMainThread_block_invoke_2 + 448
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f30b4dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2eadf5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2eab5b __CFRunLoopRun + 2347
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f2e9fc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    36  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff86193d55 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
    37  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff86193b8f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
    38  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff861939cf _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    39  AppKit                              0x00007fff87e01d96 _DPSNextEvent + 1067
    40  AppKit                              0x00007fff87e011c5 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
    41  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff917f6c11 -[NSViewServiceApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 73
    42  AppKit                              0x00007fff87df5d28 -[NSApplication run] + 682
    43  AppKit                              0x00007fff87dbefbe NSApplicationMain + 1176
    44  libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff91ee24f2 _xpc_objc_main + 793
    45  libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff91ee0f1e xpc_main + 494
    46  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff9181c7b7 xpc_connection_handler + 0
    47  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff917faac9 NSViewServiceApplicationMain + 2818
    48  com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService 0x00000001087996ec main + 208
    49  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff896d85ad start + 1
    50  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
);
    name = NSInternalInconsistencyException;
    reason = "+[NSOpenAndSavePanelService loadViewToService:isOpenPanel:appCentric:] : failed entitlements check";
    userInfo = "<null>";
}' with backtrace (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x904a2c19 __raiseError + 201
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x99387f11 objc_exception_throw + 276
    2   ViewBridge                          0x981b5cff __62-[NSRemoteViewBase advanceToConfigPhase:awaitingWindowRights:]_block_invoke + 0
    3   ViewBridge                          0x981b4518 -[NSRemoteViewBase advanceToConfigPhase] + 49
    4   ViewBridge                          0x981b6645 -[NSRemoteViewBase viewServiceMarshalProxy:withDetailedErrorHandler:] + 228
    5   ViewBridge                          0x981b6ace -[NSRemoteViewBase viewServiceMarshalProxy:withErrorHandler:] + 109
    6   ViewBridge                          0x981b62ce -[NSRemoteViewBase viewServiceMarshalProxy:] + 48
    7   ViewBridge                          0x981a88b5 -[NSRemoteViewBase bridge] + 255
    8   AppKit                              0x94e7e03c -[NSVBSavePanel init] + 689
    9   AppKit                              0x94e7dcfd +[NSSavePanel newRemotePanel] + 357
    10  AppKit                              0x94e7d94f +[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] + 108
    11  AppKit                              0x94e7d8de +[NSOpenPanel openPanel] + 33
    12  Desktops                            0x000c7935 -[TDesktopInfoController choosePicture:] + 101
    13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x993819e4 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    14  AppKit                              0x94e7d556 __36-[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke + 51
    15  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x9a8b13c9 _os_activity_initiate + 85
    16  AppKit                              0x94e7d477 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 610
    17  AppKit                              0x94e90e69 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 102
    18  AppKit                              0x94e90d5d __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 176
    19  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x9a8b13c9 _os_activity_initiate + 85
    20  AppKit                              0x94e90c8c -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 161
    21  AppKit                              0x950ed08d __48-[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:]_block_invoke1010 + 43
    22  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x9a8b13c9 _os_activity_initiate + 85
    23  AppKit                              0x94e8f039 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2744
    24  AppKit                              0x94edb64b -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 809
    25  AppKit                              0x94e8d668 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 693
    26  AppKit                              0x9547abff -[NSWindow _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6266
    27  AppKit                              0x9547c406 -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 2303
    28  AppKit                              0x94e1971f -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 567
    29  AppKit                              0x94d94bf2 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2919
    30  AppKit                              0x94be807b -[NSApplication run] + 1159
    31  AppKit                              0x94bae6a4 NSApplicationMain + 1630
    32  Desktops                            0x0007b27e +[TAppController Main] + 46
    33  Desktops                            0x00011f7a PASCALMAIN + 90
    34  Desktops                            0x00011f10 main + 32
    35  Desktops                            0x00011ecd start + 253
    36  Desktops                            0x00011df8 start + 40
)
```

Comment: Okay, I missed that part `Please note that the caller app does not crash when using NSOpenPanel, just the helper.`

Comment: @GenericPtr, did you ever figure out what was causing this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I ran aground in this too. The problem ended up being that my app lacked the necessary entitlements provisioned to allow this operation.

[image: Add file Read/Write entitlements]

In your project settings, under *App Sandbox* > *File Access* > *User Selected File* and select *Read/Write*.

Comment: I know that I shouldn't post thinks like that, but - thanks! It was it.